# how to replace the hardcoded path in python

Tags: python

In the below code how to replace the hardcoded path? 
Is there any way to read the path from some config  file?

```
import sys  
sys.path.append(r" ./build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the path from shell:

```
path = raw_input( "Insert path: ") # It will display "Insert path and will return the string entered into variable 'path'
```

Or using a file:

```
f = fopen( "<filepath>", "r" ) #open the file in reading-mode
list_of_lines = f.readlines() # read all the lines and put them in a list
f.close() # closes the file
for i in range( len(list_of_lines ) ): #cleaning from newline characters
  list_of_line[i] = list_of_line[i].strip()
```

And now, int the list_of_lines list you'll have all the lines read from the files...For example, now you can:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_lines)):
  sys.path.append( list_of_lines[i] )
```

Hope it help :)

Comment: I tried  path = raw_input( "Insert path: ") ,its working fine

Comment: But the other one flag an error NameError: name 'list _of_line' is not defined

Comment: A small mistake  list_of_line should be replaced with list_of_lines :-) in above code 's' is missing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing you can do `sys.path.insert(0, "./build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4")` which will give preference to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Python has something called `.pth` files for this purpose.